# Add a Column of Rotating Strings "Right" or "Left" in R

Tags: r

I am cleaning a data frame, and now I want to add a column to the dataframe, with rotating strings. ("Right" and "left").

For example, if the row number is odd, add "Right" if even, add "left"
What I've done so far is to create a column with the exact number of rows I need, and now I am stuck on how to build the for loop.

What I so far is this column.

```
hiip <- data.frame(hiip = 1:78)
for (hip in hiips){
    if (hip
```

I am uncertain to how to complete the for loop for this to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a logical condition with `%%` and use that to pass the values 'Right" or "Left"

```
library(dplyr)
hiip %>%
  mutate(new = c("Right", "Left")[(row_number() %%2 == 0) + 1])
```

---

Or just using the recycling

```
transform(hiip, new = c("Left", "Right")[c(1, 2)])
```